# How to check if u-boot exists in a linux device

Tags: boot, 18.04, bootloader

I am trying to remove u-boot on an embedded device to reduce boot time.
The platform I am working on is jetson Nano B01
I have followed the instructions to flash without u-boot
but I don't know how to check if the process succeeded

I tried checking version but those commands fail...

```
strings /dev/mtd0 | grep U-boot
sudo grep -a --null-data U-boot /dev/mmcbllkboot
```

fail with no such file found type of errors.

Is that confirmation that uboot doesn't exist? if not what can I do?